# Java 8 get a list out of map based on condition

Tags: java, list, lambda, java-8, java-stream

I have an `Item` class :

```
public class Item {
    String name;
    double price;
    // Getters & Setters
}
```

Now I have a map as `Map<String, List<Item>> map;` this map holds the name of the item and a corresponding list of items having the same name.

Now I want to find out all list of items matching a filter criterion.

Here is my filter `List<String> filter` basically it contains all list of names which I need to filter from map and get all the selected items as a final list.

```
List<Item> output = new ArrayList<>();
        filter.forEach(item -> {
            List<Item> list = map.get(item);
            if (list != null) {
                output .addAll(list);
            }
        });
```

Here I am using Lambda expression, now is there a way to simplify this code further using Lamda or method reference?

Comment: `List<Item> output = filter.stream().map(map::get).filter(Objects::nonNull).flatMap(List::stream).collect(Collectors.toList())`

Comment: shmosel, Thanks a lot, perfect answer. can you please suggest me a good tutorial or book that explains how to use these features.

Comment: I read a book called Java 8 in Action. But there are tons of tutorials online.

Answer (score 1):

I'd stream the filter list, flat map it the to values on the list and then collect them as a oneliner:

```
List<Item> result = 
    filter.stream()
          .flatMap(f -> map.getOrDefault(f, Collections.emptyList).stream())
          .collect(Collectors.toList());
```